# Show images in a repeater one at a time in ASP.NET WebForms

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET WebForms solution wherein I need to show pictures of a standard deck of cards, one at a time every 1000ms. The page ShuffleCards.aspx has a button to shuffle the cards and the card list at the bottom of the button is shown via a repeater. I tried to use a timer to try to show the images one at a time but what happens is, when the page is loaded for the first time (shows the unshuffled cards), after the button is shown, the timer lapses 1 second then displays all cards.

Is there anything that I miss to make this work?

**ShuffleCards.aspx**

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ShuffleCards.aspx.cs" Inherits="OpenPathExam2.ShuffleCards" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<script runat="server">


</script>


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Card Shuffler</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1>Card Shuffle Page</h1>
            <asp:Label ID="lblShuffleStatus" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
            <asp:LinkButton ID="Button2" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-lg" OnClick="Button2_Click" Text="Shuffle"> </asp:LinkButton>
        </div>
        <div>
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterImages" runat="server">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Image ID="Image" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Container.DataItem %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                    <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" OnTick="TimerTick" Interval="1000" Enabled="true" />
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>

        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

ShuffleCards.aspx.cs

```
    public partial class ShuffleCards : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public Deck deck = new Deck();
        List<String> images;
        object CardToShow;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                lblShuffleStatus.Text = "Unshuffled";
            }

        }

        protected void TimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string[] filesindirectory = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Images"));
                images = new List<string>(filesindirectory.Count());
                foreach (Card card in deck.Cards)
                {
                    Timer1.Enabled = true;
                    CardToShow = card;
                    images.Add(String.Format("~/Images/{0}", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(CardToShow + ".jpg")));
                    RepeaterImages.DataSource = images;
                    RepeaterImages.DataBind();
                    RepeaterImages.Visible = true;
                    Timer1.Enabled = false;
                }

          
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

        }
    }
```

Deck.cs

```
public class Deck
    {
        static Random r = new Random();
        public bool shuffled = false;
        Card[] cards = new Card[52];
        string[] numbers = new string[] { "A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K" };
        public Deck()
        {
            int i = 0;
            foreach (string s in numbers)
            {
                cards[i] = new Card(Suits.C, s);
                i++;

            }
            foreach (string s in numbers)
            {
                cards[i] = new Card(Suits.S, s);
                i++;

            }
            foreach (string s in numbers)
            {
                cards[i] = new Card(Suits.H, s);
                i++;

            }
            foreach (string s in numbers)
            {
                cards[i] = new Card(Suits.D, s);
                i++;
            }
        }

        public Card[] Cards
        {
            get
            {
                return cards;
            }
        }

        //Fisher-Yates Shuffle
        public void Shuffle(Card[] deck)
        {
            for (int n = deck.Length - 1; n > 0; --n)
            {
                int k = r.Next(n + 1);
                Card temp = deck[n];
                deck[n] = deck[k];
                deck[k] = temp;
            }

            shuffled = true;
        }
    }
```

Card.cs

```
public enum Suits
{
    H,
    D,
    S,
    C
}
public class Card
{
    protected Suits suit;
    protected string cardvalue;
    public Card()
    {
    }
    public Card(Suits suit2, string cardvalue2)
    {
        suit = suit2;
        cardvalue = cardvalue2;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}{1}", cardvalue, suit);
    }
}
```

Images are named AH.jpg (Ace of hearts), AC.jpg(Ace of Clubs) and so on.

Comment: You have an empty catch block in your code. Remove it! It's just going to hide issues and make it difficult to debug your code. You don't need a try/catch there.

Comment: even though I removed the try catch block, I cannot achieve the desired output

Comment: Removing the try/catch wasn't intended to solve the problem you're asking about. Rather it's to prevent you from losing important exception details in the event that something goes wrong. Empty catch block is a very bad habit to get into - simply don't do it. If you're not doing anything in the catch block that's going to bite you at some point. Please update the code in your question to reflect your new code.

Comment: yah I know that. I have a code inside there when I was debugging. I just removed it.